# Schiphol flight api, get flight information with python gets error

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to get data from a public api from schiphol (airport in Amsterdam).
Im getting this api from https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights.

I'm using python to get the flight data. In my code I get the error that the "app_id" is none while this is filled in....

the full error from the console: 
Usage: flight_info_api.py [options]

flight_info_api.py: error: Please provide an app id (-i, --app_id)

Can anybody see what is going wrong?

My code:

```
import requests
import sys
import optparse


def callPublicFlightAPI(options):
    url = 'https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights'

    headers = {
        'resourceversion': 'v4',
        'app_id': 'b209eb7f',
        'app_key': '0b6c58b5ae4595dd39785b55f438fc70'
    }

    try:
        response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as error:
        print(error)
        sys.exit()

    if response.status_code == 200:
        flightList = response.json()
        print('found {} flights.'.format(len(flightList['flights'])))
        for flight in flightList['flights']:
            print('Found flight with name: {} scheduled on: {} at {}'.format(flight['flightName'],
                                                                             flight['scheduleDate'],
                                                                             flight['scheduleTime']))
    else:
        print('''Oops something went wrong Http response code: {}{}'''.format(response.status_code, response.text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-i', '--app_id', dest='app_id',
                      help='App id used to call the API')
    parser.add_option('-k', '--app_key', dest='app_key',
                      help='App key used to call the API')

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.app_id is None:
        parser.error('Please provide an app id (-i, --app_id)')

    if options.app_key is None:
        parser.error('Please provide an app key (-key, --app_key)')

    callPublicFlightAPI(options)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to your headers:
'Accept': 'application/json'

Good luck.

EDIT:

Basically, Since you would like to receive your data as json, You will have to add 'Accept': 'application/json' to your headers. In this case, your headers will look like this:

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'resourceversion': 'v4',
    'app_id': YOUR_APP_ID,
    'app_key': YOUR_APP_KEY
}
```

And when you are going to make a request, you have to add the headers in the parameter. Your request is going to look like this:

```
response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to where and why you want the OP to add the mentioned header. This will not help others who are looking for solutions to their questions while they visit your answer on this thread.

Comment: @mishsx yes this worked for me, you needed to specify in what way you want the data to be received, could do both Json or XML.

Comment: @mishsx I added the explanation!

Comment: @RonnyGiezen I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks @nick, upvoting for good behaviour. Keep up the good work friend. :)